# Jenkins job not running after chrome driver start

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium Project that is running on `Jenkins` everyday, Today After updating `chrome driver 93` & `Jenkins 2.303.1`, When I am running this build, it does not running, in console output there is nothing after this log, anyone Please Help what should I do.

```
C:\Users\Test\eclipse-workspace\Test>java org.testng.TestNG C:\Users\Test\eclipse-workspace\Test\TestNG.xml
Sep 15, 2021 11:59:35 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Starting ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0adeaed5550e6c7e98417dac77d98a-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#1135}) on port 5299
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.

ChromeDriver was started successfully
```

After this, it just showing loader & Nothing Happened. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened for me, I used following codes to resolved this issue

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--no-sandbox"));
options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--disable-dev-shm-usage"));
options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--disable-gpu"));
```